# What do you call this elevated road structure?

Tags: image-identification

I'm looking for an English term for this:

[image]

Notice it's a single piece of road that is elevated, having another one pass underneath it. I wouldn't call it a bridge since a bridge usually goes over a natural feature like a river.

Comment: [Viaduct](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/viaduct)?

Comment: "Overpass" would be a common term in the US.  (It's an "underpass" if the bottom road is routed through a ditch so that the top road remains mostly flat.)

Comment: Overpass in the US. Most of the time what's called an overpass in the US would be called a flyover in other regions.The two words are not completely equivalent- flyover is also used in the US, but to distinguish an overpass that more literally "flies over" another. 

 I don't know if a structure as low as the one in your picture is called a flyover in, for example, the UK.

Comment: @Hot Licks - sounds like THEE answer.

Comment: @oerkelens A viaduct passes over a valley, river, etc. This structure elevates itself so another road can pass under it.

Comment: Ah, I see. The wiki page mentions that in Romance languages it is used fro structures spanning land. I guess the Dutch are taking a bit of both worlds, calling things that cross other roads also viaducts (if they cross water, their bridges, if they cross gorges or canyons they are "abroad" :P)

Comment: In order to decide, go to Yahoo and search for __overpass images__, then for __"elevated road" images__, and see which set of images is closer to your idea.

Comment: @bobro: I think 'flyover' must be regional (or highway engineer-speak) in the US.  I've only seen it used in British English.

Comment: @jamesqf : Could be both regional and highway-engineer speak. I know that "flyover" is used in Californian, among people with a blue-collar background at least, specifically for overpasses and similar constructions that "fly over" other overpasses, or from one freeway to another, and such. Let's see, googling "Caltrans flyover"... yes, there's flyover bridge, flyover ramp, flyover connector, and just plain flyover all in use.

Comment: @jamesqf: I think "flyover" is used to describe long sections of elevated road over relatively flat terrain.  Note that the terrain is built up under most of the structure in the photograph, so it doesn't qualify.  I don't know that the term is particularly regional within the U.S. except that it would mostly be used in places where many such structures exist.

Comment: The part in the middle is a bridge.

Comment: To clarify on *viaduct*: from an engineering standpoint it would need to have multiple spans to be a viaduct. @oerkelens link hints at it by saying *"a long elevated roadway usually consisting of a series of short spans"*. What it crosses is not relevant as to whether it is a viaduct or not (but it *is* relevant as to whether it's a flyover/overpass or not). And a viaduct is always a bridge, a bridge is not always a viaduct.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

["Overpass"](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/overpass?s=t)

> **noun**
>   1. A road, pedestrian walkway, railroad, bridge, etc., crossing over some barrier, as another road or walkway.
>
> *www.dictionary.com*

Comment: Referring to Chenmunka's answer, in America at least, "flyover" has a similar use, though it evokes a higher, more disconnected feeling in the road. I've seen it used for the ramps used to switch between major highways at an interchange, particularly at the more complex interchanges.

Comment: I'm from the American Midwest and have never heard of "flyover" used in such a sense. It may be a regionalism.

Comment: @AndrewCoonce: "Overpass" is a regionalism.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Maybe so, but it's a strong enough regionalism that I've never heard "flyover" in Cincinnati OH, Columbus OH, or Madison WI.

Comment: @AndrewCoonce: I guess my point is that not everybody lives in Cincinnati OH USA, Columbus OH USA, or Madison WI USA!

Comment: My comment was merely provided as regional context. They're looking for a single word, and someone said that flyover has a similar use. If they're in the American Midwest, which is the context I provided for my comment, they're unlikely to find many people who know what a flyover is and should use the overpass term.

Comment: I have heard "flyover", but usually for some unusual structure, not a relatively mundane overpass.

Comment: None of those cities _have_ flyovers! In U.S. English a flyover is an overpass that also passes over _other_ overpasses. You generally see them only in complex highway interchanges. (But in British English, a flyover is a _very long bridge_ passing over a road, usually parallel to it.)

Comment: @Michael - A flyover in the UK doesn't need to be a very long bridge. As a UK civil engineer, I would describe this structure as a flyover.

Comment: All this Flyover/Overpass discussion proves is that there is no *single* common word for this structure around the world. As the OP asked for "...AN English term..." both Overpass and Flyover are fully correct answers in my view

Answer (score 38):

In Britain, this is known as a *flyover*.

One road flies over another.  Sometimes, *overpass* is used but this is much less common.

Comment: I agree in BrE we're much more likely to use ***flyover*** in general. But speaking for myself at least, if I'm describing a major urban throughway with both types of "route crossover" I'd often refer to them as ***overpasses*** and ***underpasses***.

Comment: In British English, it's almost inevitably a flyover. I've never heard it called an overpass. Here are two (of different sizes) very close to each other: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hammersmith_flyover and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hogarth_Roundabout

Comment: This term is also used in Canada but is far less frequent than *overpass*.

Comment: @Eric I think Canada tends towards American for automotive vocabulary.

Comment: @ChrisW Yeah, just thought it was worth noting that both were understood and acceptable.

Comment: The pictures that @abligh linked to are both what I would call _flyovers_: the entire road is elevated above the terrain and ‘flies’, supported only by pillars of some kind. The kind in this question, however, is somewhat different in that the terrain is actually raised up to the level of the road. The road doesn’t ‘fly’ over anything: apart from the place where the other road crosses it, you can’t walk under the elevated road. That makes it an _overpass_ to me, rather than a _flyover_.

Comment: I think depending on the audience - for example in India where we lean towards BrE, this would only ever be called a flyover. The word overpass is rarely used here outside perhaps some technical documentation. I suspect the same holds true for many BrE speaking geographies.

Answer (score 8):

Well, it all depends on what specifically you want named. As a civil engineer with bridge design experience, I'm happy to provide the technical terms.

The exact bit where one road passes over another is called a bridge. (No, a bridge does not have to pass over a "natural feature"). But the term "bridge" doesn't cover the ramps either side - these are approach embankments supported by mechanically stabilised earth walls.

To describe the whole thing, the previous answers of overpass or flyover would both be valid engineering terms. For this particular case, where the structure carries traffic which is avoiding a junction of the road it is travelling on, flyover would be the most typically used in the UK.

Comment: So in purely engineering terms, whether the elevation is provided by pillars or approach embankments suppoerted by mechanically stabilised earth walls does not influence what the structure is termed? That’s very interesting. As I just commented on Chenmunka’s answer (before I read yours), that would be the main differentiator between the two for me: whether the elevated road looks like it’s ‘flying’, or like it’s on a little hill that the road it’s travelling on goes ‘through’.

Comment: @Janus - If there was never any actual bridge in it, then it wouldn't be a flyover or overpass, it would just be an elevated road. If you had a multi-span bridge supported on piers (or "pillars") then as well as being a flyover/overpass it would also be a viaduct. That said, if you asked me to describe a flyover I would describe a multi-span viaduct; if you asked me to describe an overpass I'd describe a steel footbridge which connects the footways either side of a road. Neither of these "typical" uses of the words stops the same words being used to describe the OP's structure though.

Answer (score 6):

I think it is also  called [road bridge](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Road+bridge):

> - a structure spanning and providing passage over a gap or barrier, such as a river or roadway.
>
>   - something resembling or analogous to this structure in form or function:

(TFD)